# ParquetSharp's UTC adjustment

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, parquet

I am trying to use the ParquetSharp library (https://github.com/G-Research/ParquetSharp) to write some Parquet files from an SQL server database.
As the original data is not adjusted to UTC, I want the output parquet file to also be "datetime64[ns]" instead of "datetime64[ns, UTC]".

I have tried changing the DateTime with argument LogicalType.Timestamp(isAdjustedToUtc: false) but this causes an exception as the original data is of type DateTime.

```
columns[i] = new Column(typeof(DateTime?), cdt.Schema[i].Name,LogicalType.Timestamp(isAdjustedToUtc: false, timeUnit: TimeUnit.Nanos));
```

I try to use LogicalWriterOverride as suggested in the documentation:

```
using (var dtWriter = groupWriter.NextColumn().LogicalWriterOverride<DateTime?>())
{
   dtWriter.WriteBatch(dtArray);
}
```

But a NotSupportedException gets thrown:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'unsupported logical system type System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] with logical type Timestamp(isAdjustedToUTC=false, timeUnit=nanoseconds, is_from_converted_type=false, force_set_converted_type=false)'

Edit: I managed to find somewhat of a solution, that does not conflict with the original data. In `LogicalType.Timestamp(isAdjustedToUtc: false, timeUnit: TimeUnit.Nanos)`  I changed to `TimeUnit.Micros` as the DateTime type does not support Nanos precision, so then I override `NextColumn().LogicalWriterOverride<DateTime?>` and the UTC is removed in the generated parquet file, while the precision is in microseconds.

Comment: You're missing the converter factory.  Have you defined one and assigned it?  You need to inherit from `LogicalWriteConverterFactory`, implement your converter, then assign it to `LogicalWriteConverterFactory` on `ParquetFileWriter`.  That's the name of the property, don't know why they used a type name for a property name.  In other words, there is no built in conversion, you need to provide one.  Note `DateTime?` is not the same type as `DateTime`.

Comment: I am a little confused on how to properly use the ConverterFactory although i read the documentation.
`ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer(4096);
converterFactory.GetConverter<DateTime, TimeSpanNanos>(columnDescriptor, byteBuffer: buffer) ;`

The columnDescriptor has to be taken from the initialized column ?

Comment: When you say _"SQL server database"_, did you forget to `Tag your RDBMS`?

Comment: I did, but i added it now as tag. Nevertheless I believe my main issue to be derived from the implementation of the Converters in ParquetSharp, and It's rather necessary for me to use ParquetSharp, due to the zstd compression available, and its relative speed compared to Parquet.NET.